# Laravel queue removing s3 directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, queue, jobs, laravel-5.3

This method am I using to destroy a users directory on `Amazon S3` based on his/her `Id`:

```
public function destroyDirectory(User $user)
{
    if($this->directoryExists($user->id))
    {
        $job = (new DestroyDirectory($user))->onQueue('destroydirectory');
        dispatch($job);
    }
}
```

This is how my `DestroyDirectory` job looks like:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function handle()
{
    Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory('users/' . $this->user->id);
}
```

Locally this is working. But on my production server it only removes the file in the database (not in s3). I'm using more queues in my `Laravel 5.3` application and they do work. So what could be going on here. I'm using `Laravel Forge`. When I try this:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return bool
 */
public function destroyDirectory(User $user)
{
    if($this->directoryExists($user->id))
    {
        Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory('users/' . $this->user->id);
    }
}
```

It's working!

In my `failed_jobs` table I do not receive any errors. But I guess the job is being executed because it removes records from my database but not in `s3`!

Comment: Did you solve this? I also have problem getting my queue talk to s3

Comment: I just made all queues again and suddenly it worked. Very strange.